# window.location.replace going into infinite loop. How to change url in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, webbrowser-control

I want to change the url on scroll horizontally. 
Used 
 **window.location.replace** 
 **window.location.assign**
**event.preventDefault()**;

http://igv.org/web/examples/events/track-url.html#/locus/chr1:155,167,355-155,190,548 
 
 on scrolling, url changes to this

http://igv.org/web/examples/events/track-url.html#/locus/chr1:155,168,900-155,192,093

**But it reloading or refreshing continuously** 


 Used below steps

```
var myIgvBrowser = igv.createBrowser(div,options);
myIgvBrowser.on('locuschange', function (referenceFrame, label) {
    var change_url = HASH_PREFIX + label + id + id_val;
    alert(change_url);
    // if (window.location.href !== redirectLocation) {
    window.location.replace(change_url);
    // return false;
});
```

***&***

```
var myIgvBrowser = igv.createBrowser(div,options);
myIgvBrowser.on('locuschange', function (referenceFrame, label, event) {
    var change_url = HASH_PREFIX + label + id + id_val;

    window.location.replace(change_url);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**alert(change_url);** - working 
on scrolling, alert shows changed positions but window.location.replace not working 
How to solve this and if any help thanks guys in advance

Comment: Before this line `window.location.replace(change_url);` Please share the output of following log statement `console.log( window.location, change_url )`.

Comment: Output of console.log
Location → http://127.0.0.1:1000/igv.html ?r=chr1:1-249,250,621&id=9007
Location → http://127.0.0.1:1000/igv.html ?r=chr1:36,933,790-36,933,830&id=9007

Comment: chr1:1-249,250,621 I am not giving this position in URL.But somehow it taking by default. I think because of this infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are doing a `window.location.replace` every time your page loads up and you don't check if you really need to do `window.location.replace` or not.

You need to check if `location.replace` is really required or not at first place, since **you are only changing the hash value**, replace it with

```
window.location.hash = label + id + id_val;
```

Comment: i didn't notice previously but label + id + id_val of URL coming twice with  label + id + id_val  #label + id + id_val. And later part is changing the posiitons but first part not changing positions.

Comment: can you add more information - what is `label`, `id` and `id_val`? How/when their value changes? Preferably add a new question for the same.

Comment: label = 155,167,355-155,190,548 (positions which changes while scrolling ) ,    id = "&id=",    val= folder number like '1000'

Comment: used window.replace with empty strings but again going into infinite loop

Comment: You can't use window.replace since it will essentially redirect the browser to same URL. You just need to debug why hash values are not getting updated correctly.

Comment: OK. this is the below link I used for my javascript.
view-source:http://igv.org/web/examples/events/track-url.html#/locus/chr1:155,165,140-155,188,536.

Is there any way to delete that part or by replace with empty strings or something